# invalid use of incomplete typedef in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, definition, incomplete-type

I'm implementing a data structure in C and I get this error in my test file. Without adding code because then that would be a huge post with a ton of code to go through, but here's what my code looks like:

```
header.h file:
typedef struct array Arr;

functions.c file:
#include "header.h"

struct array{
int number;
int size;
char *names;
}

main.c file:
#include "header.h"

bool function(const Arr *const variable)
{

for (int i = 0; i < variable->size; i++)
{
 variable->number[i] = i;
}
}
```

and so I get the error mentioned in the title referring to Arr*->*number and Arr*->*size. What I suspect to be the issue is that Arr is only typedefed but not defined. If that's the case, how can I resolve it?

Here's the main code:

```
  main.c
#include <stdio.h>
  #include "header.h"
  int main(){
  set *setA = set_empty();

  set_insert(69,setA );

  set_insert(15, setA);

    set *setB = set_empty();

    set_insert(12,setB );

    set_insert(15, setB);

  set *setDiff = set_difference(setA, setB);

  printf("\n");

  print_set(setDiff);

  bool diff = verify_difference(setDiff, setA, setB);
}

bool verify_difference(const set *const setDiff, const set *const setA, const struct set *const setB)

{

  bool answer = true;

  for (int x = 0; x < setDiff->size; x++)
  {
          if (set_member_of(setDiff->array[x], setA) && set_member_of(setDiff->array[x], setB))
          {
                  answer = false;
                  break;
          }
  }
  return answer;
}

header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct set set;

set *set_empty();

void set_insert(const int value, set *s);

bool set_member_of(const int value, const set *const s);

functions.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
struct set {

    int capacity;

    int size;

    char *array;

};

set *set_empty()
{

struct set *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct set));

ptr->size = 0;

ptr->array = malloc(sizeof(char));

ptr->capacity = 1;

return ptr;
}
void set_insert(const int value, set *s)
{
    if (!set_member_of(value, s)) {
        int bit_in_array = value; // To make the code easier to read

        // Increase the capacity if necessary
        if (bit_in_array >= s->capacity) {
            int no_of_bytes = bit_in_array / 8 + 1;
            s->array = realloc(s->array, no_of_bytes);
            for (int i = s->capacity / 8 ; i < no_of_bytes ; i++) {
                s->array[i] = 0;
            }
            s->capacity = no_of_bytes * 8;
        }

        // Set the bit
        int byte_no = bit_in_array / 8;
        int bit = 7 - bit_in_array % 8;
        s->array[byte_no] = s->array[byte_no] | 1 << bit;
        s->size++;
    }
}
set *set_difference(const set *const s1, const set *const s2)
{

struct set *s = set_empty();


for (int i = 0; i < s1->size; i++)
{
  if (!set_member_of(s1->array[i], s2))
  {
    set_insert(s1->array[i], s);
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < s2->size; i++)
{
  if (!set_member_of(s2->array[i], s1))
  {
    set_insert(s2->array[i], s);
  }
}

return s;
}

bool set_member_of(const int value, const set *const s)
{
    int bit_in_array = value;

    if (bit_in_array >= s->capacity) {
        return false;
    }

    int byte_no = bit_in_array / 8;
    int bit = 7 - bit_in_array % 8;
    char the_byte = s->array[byte_no];

    return the_byte & 1 << bit;
}
```

Comment: Please post the *real* code and the *real*, verbatim error messages you're seeing, in your question. Copy/paste makes both typo's impossible, and clarity abundant.

Comment: @WhozCraig it would require me to post at least 90 lines of code for it to make sense, I thought it would be more convenient that way, like writing pseudo code.

Comment: Compile-time errors aren't produced by pseudocode; they're produces by *code*. That is why a proper [mcve] is so important when asking for analysis and potential solutions to such problems. If we can copy/paste/compile using *only* what you post, and produce the results you're getting, we can *very* quickly tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Go ahead, let's see the code. Also, share the compile command & error.

Comment: you must have the definiton of `struct arr` visible in each c file that uses it. Put it in header.h

Comment: @SparKot just added it

Comment: Consider just not using a `typedef`. Your code will be more readable and have less namespace pollution.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the structure shall be available in main. Otherwise the compiler does not know whether there is the data member `number` in the structure referred in this statement

```
Arr->number[i] = i;
```

Moreover in any case this statement is incorrect because `Arr` is a type specifier and according to the structure definition the data member `number` is not an array

It seems you mean

```
variable[i].number = i;
```

But as the function parameter

```
bool function(const Arr *const variable)
```

is declared as a pointer to a constant object then you may not change pointed to data members of the structure.

So either move the definition of the function `function` from `main.c` in `functions.c` or place the structure definition in the header file.

And there is a typo

```
Typedef struct array Arr;
^^T
```

you need to use lower case letter

```
typedef struct array Arr;
```

Comment: You are totally right with regards to changing Arr to variable, just edited it in my post. Now, moving the struct definition to main.c would work, but it's specifically mentioned in our assignment that it stays the way I have in my post, it's part of the assignment so unfortionatelly  I can't change it.

Comment: @JonathanF Move the structure definition from functions.c in the header. Or move the function  function from main in the functions.c.

Answer (score 1):

I can only hazard a guess. Your code snippet could be wrong.

Move the structure definition to `header.h` & check.

```c
    //header.h file:
    typedef struct array Arr;
    
    struct array{
        int number;
        int size;
        char *names;
    };
```

Comment: That would definitely work, but it's part of the assignment to have the structure definition in main.c and try to solve it that way.